# Is there an Index(Match()) Equivalent for Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

First off: total JS/Apps Script novice here. : )

I'm trying to replace some Google Sheets formulas I have with Apps Script, and was wondering how I would code the following if statement:

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function onFormSubmitTest(e) {
    //Open spreadsheet based on URL
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('sheetnamehere');
    //Set as Active
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
    //Set Tabs as Variables
    var Rsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emailer");
    var Lsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Unique Databases");

    //----Set last Rows as Variables----
    // Gets Values from different sections, filters arrays to non-null values off of [0] index
    var formResponses = Rsheet.getRange("N3:N").getValues().filter(function(row) {return row[0]}).sort();
    var databaseNames = Lsheet.getRange("A2:B").getValues().filter(function(row) {return row[0]}).sort();
    var developerNames = Lsheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues().filter(function(row) {return row[0]}).sort();

    // Attempt finding current process owner's e-mail address

    // Emailer Rows to Process
    var startRow = 3; // First row of data to process.  This is required because of various formatting messed up the opportunity for Last Row being the only row in the dataRange.

    // Number of rows to process
    var numRows = formResponses.length;

    // Fetch the range of cells
    var dataRange = Rsheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 30);

    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
```

The statement I'm trying to load into a variable is if the value of var data [16] = var databaseNames [0], return var databaseNames [1]. I'm pretty sure that all arrays are coded correctly to be sorted in ascending order for faster indexing.

Thanks!

Any help/advice you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. It is not clear what you are asking. Can you re-phrase your question?

Comment: Hey @Jason. I'm trying to load a variable with the result from a match between 2 arrays, based off of a 0 index. One array has 31 columns, one has 2. For whatever the value is in the 16th column of var data, I want to return the value in var databaseNames [1] where the 2 are the same. With a formula, I'd use =index(rangeofreturnvalues(match(value, rangeofmatchvalues, 0)).

Comment: @pnuts got it. I'll definitely reference that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to data[16] and databaseNames[0], but note that range.getValues() returns a two-dimensional array. databaseNames[0] would be the first array element in dataBaseNames[], which is equivalent to the first row in the range.

It's not clear to me whether you are looking to return an array or a single value. If you are just trying to figure out how to return the value in databaseNames[i][1] when databaseNames[i][0] = x, something like this should do it:

```
findMatch = function(x) {
  var returnValue;
  // assuming databaseNames exists in parent or global scope...
  databaseNames.forEach(function(row){
    if (row[0] === x) returnValue = row[1];
  });
  return returnValue;
}
```

If you are looking to return an array of values that match data[i][16], you could do var newArray = data.map(findMatch), and modify the function to set the comparison value to x[16] instead of x.

Comment: Hey @Nico, I tried the snippet you have, and I can't get it to return what I'm expecting. I'm guessing that my question is still terribly formatted, so I've made a quick [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JS5Iwx60Zk7VL8lYz6Yj7ew4eYPhl2NkB2UeCoOR2sg/edit#gid=572642755). In the sheet, Emailer!E:E has a text string in it. In Emailer!F:F, I'm trying to return the value that matches from 'Unique Databases'!B:B, when Emailer!E:E = 'Unique Databases'!A:A. Thanks so much for your patience, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @swolfe2 it looks to me like you got it working by converting the values on the Unique Databases tab into a lookup object, which probably performs a little better anyway. My recommendation was intended to work with a two-dimensional array, so is no longer relevant. One suggestion: doing getRange() and setValue() on a bunch of individual cells can get pretty pokey if your sheet gets larger. Consider forming your output data into a 2D array and using setValues() on all rows at once.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not totally clear, but I think this might be what you are looking for. In your question perhaps edit it give a concrete example of the structure and nature of the data.

```
var result = "";

var data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32];
var databaseNames  = [16,19];

var a = data[16]; // 16
var b = databaseNames[0]; //16

if(a === b){
   result = a //16
}
```

Comment: apologies for the difficulty in communicating. :( It's hard to put out an example that wouldn't have business data  in it. The var values I'm referencing are in my code in the first post, including what creates var data and var databaseNames. Var databaseNames is 2 columns, which are a key>value pair. I'm trying to return the result of the second column in databaseNames based off of the match between the first column and another variable.